# Ideal image size and format

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm building an image gallery type of application and i want to know what is the best image size and format (.png or .jpg) to be stored in the app.

I also want to know what is the best and most efficient way to store and load images natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PNGs are optimized for the OS when they are added to your app bundle.  To improve performance of your app you want to:

1. Make sure the images have no alpha channel in them, otherwise the OS will try and blend them.
2. Resize your images to be the size they will end up in the UI.  This will reduce the read bandwidth for the drawing, saving you memory and boosting performance.

Images in the app bundle can be read into UIImageViews:

```
UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
```

This will cache the image for you, which is good for lots of small images re-used a lot.  For larger infrequently used images you want to use +imageFromContentsOfFile: instead of +imageNamed:

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know iOS and xCode optimizes PNG formats and performs better with them.

You may want to check out this :

http://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/